# Glib.h error while trying to compile an application

Tags: compiling, glib

I've been trying to compile this app from source https://code.launchpad.net/gala and i keep getting this message when i run MAKE:

```
Scanning dependencies of target gala 
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/gala.dir/src/DBus.c.o 
/home/camilo/notifications/build/src/DBus.c:21:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory 
compilation terminated. 
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gala.dir/src/DBus.c.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gala.dir/all] Error 2 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Even though I' have installed glib and there is the glib.h file

```
camilo@ian:~$ find /usr -iname glib.h
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h
```

Is it a bug form the application or is it something wrong with my system?

Comment: Compiler doesn't know the path of `glib.h`. Use **CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/glib-2.0'** option with `make` command and compile

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The issue was i didn't have installed the [gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev [image: Install gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev) package.